# Download all files in a directory (without index): file names in increasing numbers

Tags: command-line

I would like to save my online textbook for offline usage, and through Google Chrome's "Network" panel I found out the path of the images. They can be accessed through the browser and downloaded using curl if given the correct configuration ("copy cURL"). The files look like the following: "https://c*.m*.com/r*/p*/R*/5*/5*/2*/O*/images/page.svgz", where  is the page number with four digits, e.g. page0258.svgz. I would like to batch download them using some shell syntaxes. I use fish, but I can also use other shells.

How would I achieve that four number pattern expansion on the command line?

Comment: Merging files is very different answer than how to glob / abstract a pattern of file names. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99210/mac-os-x-how-to-merge-pdf-files-in-a-directory-according-to-their-file-names? Or post a second question if you have an example of merging you can’t solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl` can do this automatically for you (see the beginning of `man curl` for more details about this):

```
curl -O https://c.m.com/r*/p*/R*/5*/5*/2*/O*/images/page[0000-9999].svgz
```

PS: This assumes you will expand `r*/p*/R*/5*/5*/2*/O*/` before running `curl`,

Comment: How would you do this for wget?

Comment: @JoyJin `wget` doesn't directly support this. If there is an index/root page you could run `wget -r -l 99 https://host/index`, or you could try `wget https://c.m.com/r*/p*/R*/5*/5*/2*/O*/images/page00{0..9{0..9}.svgz` for the pages 0000 til 0099.